# tf.WholeFileReader() not reading

Tags: python, tensorflow

My code seems to find the jpeg image perfectly, because if I mess up the path it will not proceed, also I printed out the return from match_filenames_once and there was the correct list of image files. However the following code does not seem to load the images into the queue. What is wrong with the filename_queue?

Here is my code:

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
tf.train.match_filenames_once("./resized2/*.jpg"),shuffle=False)

image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
myfilename, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file)
# Start a new session to show example output.

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()

    sess.run(init_op)

    # Start populating the filename queue.

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    for i in range(1): #length of your filename list
        image_tensor = image.eval() #here is your image Tensor :) 
    print(myfilename)
    print(image.shape)
    #Image.fromarray(np.asarray(image_tensor)).show()

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Here is the output:

```
Tensor("ReaderReadV2:0", shape=(), dtype=string)
(?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: You mean - `print(image_tensor.shape)`?

Comment: yes, that prints out (225, 300, 3) which are the dimensions of the image

Answer (score 0):

Try to print shape of `image_tensor`

```
print(image_tensor.shape)
```

`image` in your code is Tensor, and it has unknown size, because it come to graph from arbitrary jpeg image, and TF can't define it's size, when TF create graph. But `image_tensor` is `np.array` with image loaded from disk.